# Extend mouseleave area to include button & new popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, datatemplate

I have a popup appear directly beside a button on Mouseover. I need to keep popup open when mouse crosses over from button to popup. I also need the popup to close when the button leaves either the button OR popup. It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014833/how-to-make-a-popup-stays-open-when-mouseover-popup-in-wpf) post, so please forgive me, but no working solution was provided there.

In essence, I want to expand the mouseleave area to include button and popup so mouse can travel over both and mouseleave fires if mouse leaves either one.

```
        <Popup x:Key="CustomPopup" x:Name="samplePopup" Margin="0" AllowsTransparency="False" StaysOpen="True">

        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="AntiqueWhite">
            <WebBrowser x:Name="PopBrowser" local:WebBrowserUtility.Body="{Binding Path=Value}" Height="400" Width="500"/>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Trying in code behind, I added a timer to allow mouse to get from button to popup (even though I have no offset), then added an If statement to keep it open if over popup.

```
    Popup popUp { get; set; }

    private void ButtonMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button currentButton = sender as Button;
        popUp = (Popup)FindResource("CustomPopup");
        DelayedExecutionService.DelayedExecute(() =>
        {
            if (currentButton.IsMouseOver)
            {
                popUp.PlacementTarget = currentButton;
                popUp.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
                popUp.HorizontalOffset = -5;
                popUp.StaysOpen = true;
                popUp.IsOpen = true;
            }

        });
    }

    private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DelayedExecutionService.DelayedExecute(() =>
        {
            if (popUp.IsMouseDirectlyOver)
            {
                popUp.IsOpen = true;
                MessageBox.Show("over popup");  //Not recognizing this.
            }
            else
                popUp.IsOpen = false;
                MessageBox.Show("not over popup"); //I get this even if mouse is over popup.
        });
    }
```

This GIF shows MouseLeave only for the popup, which is very inconvenient with my grid of buttons:

[image]

Comment: Use `MouseEnter` event of Button and handle from code.

Comment: Thanks Anjum. I think that got me much closer (I updated my code above), but seems to me in order for it to work from code... I need to be able to check the mouse position of both controls in same MouseLeave event. Any reason why I'm unable to check popUp.IsMouseDirectlyOver from the button's mouseLeave event?

Comment: What non-sense u r doing. It is such a simple thing to do.

Comment: Lol - I am learning

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Btn" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter_1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Popup x:Name="Popup1" MouseLeave="Popup_MouseLeave_1" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Btn}" Placement="Bottom">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Some popup text !"/>
            <Button Content="Close"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Conceptual code :

```
        private void Popup_MouseLeave_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Popup1.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void Button_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Popup1.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

Tell if this doesn work.

Comment: That's simply open & close popup from button. I need popup to stay open if mouse moves from button to  the popup. I can't just make the mouse leave event  to popup instead though bc if user leaves button (not into popup) it still needs to close.

Comment: @ctalley5 This code doesnt close the popup when user moves mouse away from the button.

Comment: Apologies I switched to phone and didn't see the xaml. Mouseleave needs to work for Button also... so if the mouse doesn't go to popup (and user moves on to something else) it will close.

Comment: Added clarity to original question. Need to extend mouseleave to include both button and popup.

Comment: @ctalley5 post an image demonstrating ur issue, or use screen-to-gif converter to post animated image

Comment: Added a gif. Hope it clarifies. Thanks Anjum.

Comment: @ctalley5 use a boolean variable and handle appropriate events